# Don't show "This app won't run without google play services" dialog

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I use Google Play Services in my app, but it isn't necessary to run. However, when a device don't have Google Play Services, it shows a dialog which shows: This app won't run without google play services.

Question is, can I change this text? I couldn't find.

My Code:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I guess you could just show a custom dialog instead of `apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();`

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: I'll just post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could just show a custom dialog instead of `apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();`