# Remove Google play not supported message

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I always get this message when i dont have Google play services installed.

Normally that would be totally fine, but now that huawei dont use google playstore i really want to remove that popup. Is going to be extremly annoying for my users to get this message everytime they open the app.

How do i make the popup not show to the users? Do any of you guys know where this message comes from? Is it firebase that does it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a custom dialog instead of this one.

```
  private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, 
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722800/dont-show-this-app-wont-run-without-google-play-services-dialog)

[Another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750961/huawei-p40-google-play-services-dialog)